# 0/K knapsack. How to solve?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am trying to learn Dynamic programming. I came across: https://youtu.be/U4O3SwDamA4?t=1407
I know basics of DP although they are not yet intuitive for me. Now, he talks about

1. 0/1 knapsack
2. 0/inf knap sack

and finally 0/k knapsack

While i tried to search 0/k knapsack, I am getting optimised solution (O(nS)) and not the solution that is extracted from 0/1 directly and have complexity of O(nKS). Anyone having nay resource to share or having a good grasp for the same is welcomed :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "naïve" solution the presenter is briefly mentioning has runtime complexity *O(KS)*, given the way he defined *K* to be the sum of all the item limits. The idea is to convert it into a 0/1 problem by making *k<sub>i</sub>* copies of each item type.

Assume you've got *k<sub>0</sub>* items of type 0, *k<sub>1</sub>* items of type 1, and so on (so those are the limits to how many items you may take of each type). *K* is the total number of items (the sum of all the *k<sub>i</sub>*). Now, if you take this collection of items and start considering *every* item to be distinct from all the others, you have a 0/1 problem! The first item of type 0 is now item 0 in our new problem, the second item of type 0 is item 1 in our new problem, the last item of type 0 is item *k<sub>0</sub> - 1* in our new problem - and they all have weight *w<sub>0</sub>* and value *v<sub>0</sub>*. The first item of type 1 is item *k<sub>0</sub>* in our new problem, and so on. So we can now solve this as a 0/1 knapsack problem, but it's got *K* items instead of *n*; thus, the complexity is *O(KS)*. However, if you define *K* to be the *average* of all the *k<sub>i</sub>*, or if every item has the same limit *K*, the complexity is indeed *O(nKS)*.